pyspark UDF raises "No module named" error
I have a dataframe with a country descriptor ds_pais in English. I want to use GoogleTranslator to add a column via .withColumn that translates from english to spanish that country descriptor.
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def translate(to_translate):
    return GoogleTranslator(source='en', target='es').translate(to_translate)

translate_udf = udf(lambda x: translate(x), StringType())

df_pais_traducido = df_campo_calculado.withColumn('ds_pais_es', translate_udf(df_campo_calculado.ds_pais))

display(df_pais_traducido.select('ds_pais', 'ds_pais_es'))

but when I run it I get this Error
PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 815, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 651, in read_udfs
    udfs.append(read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf, udf_index=i))
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 376, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 88, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 174, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 472, in loads
    return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deep_translator'

Why isn't the udf finding GoogleTranslator?
EDIT: I'm running this on a Microsoft Fabric Notebook using PySpark (Python).

ensure that the package is installed on all nodes in the cluster

After resetting the PySpark session this started working. If it fails again I'll try with the Workspace Environment and install there the packages.

This error indicates that the Python interpreter running your PySpark application cannot locate the deep_translator library. This library is not part of the standard PySpark installation, so you need to install it separately.
If you're running PySpark on a cluster, you might need to install deep_translator on all worker nodes to ensure it's available for distributed computations.
or
pip install deep-translator

This will download and install the deep_translator library into your Python environment.
